# Python - How to apply function to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I am a beginner for python and learning python from *"Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"*.

I dont understand how a new function applies to dictionary in a tic-tac-toe board.

Thanks

1. Why is it necessary to include the argument `board` in `def printBoard(board)`?
2. Why do we need to add `board` before `board['top-L']`?  I don't understand why does the function work as the previous line only define `theBoard` but not `board`.

```py
theBoard = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O', 'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M':'X', 'mid-R': ' ', 'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}

def printBoard(board):
   print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
   print('-+-+-')
   print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
   print('-+-+-')
   print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])
printBoard(theBoard)
```

Comment: 1. When you pass something to function, there should be something at the receiving end to capture. 2. `theBoard` passed to function is called `board` inside function. The argument `board` receives the value of `theBoard`.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know more about the basic. 1) why dont i have the receiving end for the following function ```def printabc():
  print('abc')
  
printabc()```    2) Could we use "theBoard" instead of replacing it with another argument known as "board"?  Why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for the first question, but for the second, the answer is yes, but it would be very confusing. When you have a function parameter (e.g. board in this case), you're essentially telling the function "I have an object that we'll call this particular name within the function." If you have a variable in the global scope called "theBoard" and a variable in the smaller function scope called "theBoard," you might confuse yourself.

Comment: 1) Because you don't pass anything to function. 2) Ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. We need to include the argument "board" in printBoard. Generally, dictionary "theBoard" is not guaranteed to be in scope (a.k.a. accessible) within the function. To make this code as general as possible, and allow it to print a dictionary in this general format, we need to pass the dictionary to be printed as a parameter to the function. However, if you wanted to import this function from a different file/module, you'd run into some problems: the function will not be able to find a variable called "theBoard." This is less clear in a language like Python, and if you replace the references to "board" to "theBoard" above, this will indeed work, since "theBoard" is in the global scope.
2. In a similar vein, "board" within the function definition refers to whatever you passed in as a parameter. In this case, it's the dictionary `theBoard`. To see this, note that the function call `printBoard(theBoard)` is the actual line that does the printing. So imagine if every reference to parameter `board` in the body of the function definition was actually a reference to the dictionary `theBoard.`

In other words, I'd read up/practice the concept of scoping in programming languages, which I believe will make this example less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you learn Python, stick with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions: here, you should use `snake_case` variables names instead of `CamelCase` names (see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). Now, let me rewrite the code snippet:

```
def print_board(board):
   print(board['top-L'] + '|' + board['top-M'] + '|' + board['top-R'])
   print('-+-+-')
   print(board['mid-L'] + '|' + board['mid-M'] + '|' + board['mid-R'])
   print('-+-+-')
   print(board['low-L'] + '|' + board['low-M'] + '|' + board['low-R'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_board = {'top-L': 'O', 'top-M': 'O', 'top-R': 'O', 'mid-L': 'X', 'mid-M':'X', 'mid-R': ' ', 'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'X'}
    print_board(the_board)
```

You have two different parts: 1. the function definition ; 2. the main part of the program.

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not mandatory, but marks the block as the *entry point* of the program. Have a look at the function signature (what's after the `def` keyword): you have the name if the function (`print_board`) and, between parentheses, the parameters (here: on parameter named `board`).Try to think of the body of the function as a block that knows the values of its parameters and *nothing else* (this behaviour can be different if you play with scopes, see @tchainzzz's answer). The body of the function uses its parameter to print a board.

The counterpart is: when you call a function, you have to give this function the parameters it expects, because the function knows nothing else. Here, `the_board` is the value of the parameter on the `print_board` function call. But try to pass another value:

```
>>> print_board({'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': 'XYZ', 'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M':' ', 'mid-R': 'TUV', 'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': 'ABC'})
 | |XYZ
-+-+-
 | |TUV
-+-+-
 | |ABC
```

Or no value:

```
>>> print_board()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: print_board() missing 1 required positional argument: 'board'
```

Or two values:

```
>>> print_board(the_board, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: print_board() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Or a totally different value:

```
>>> print_board(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>> print_board([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I hope you get it! These scopes are here to help you understand what's going on in your program. You don't have to read two thousands lines of code to find the place where `board` was defined: when you read the function, you assume it was defined somewhere and that's all.